# "Достать" элемент из списка

Tags: python

Из списка:

```
lst = [{
  'update_id': 138638308, 
  'message': {
    'message_id': 215, 
    'from': {
      'id': 2999, 
      'is_bot': False, 
      'first_name': 'Yuri'}, 
    'chat': {
      'id': 77777777, 
      'first_name': 'Yuri'}
    }
  }]
```

"достать" `'id': 77777777` и показать в формате `77777777`.
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Смотрите, постепенно (результат - `lst[0]['message']['chat']['id']` - в конце):

```
lst[0]
lst[0]['message']
lst[0]['message']['chat']
lst[0]['message']['chat']['id']
```

В консоли:

```
In[16]: lst = [{'update_id': 138638308, 'message': {'message_id': 215, 'from': {'id': 2999, 'is_bot': False, 'first_name': 'Yuri'}, 'chat': {'id': 77777777, 'first_name': 'Yuri'}}}]

In[17]: lst[0]
Out[17]: 
{'message': {'chat': {'first_name': 'Yuri', 'id': 77777777},
  'from': {'first_name': 'Yuri', 'id': 2999, 'is_bot': False},
  'message_id': 215},
 'update_id': 138638308}

In[18]: lst[0]['message']
Out[18]: 
{'chat': {'first_name': 'Yuri', 'id': 77777777},
 'from': {'first_name': 'Yuri', 'id': 2999, 'is_bot': False},
 'message_id': 215}

In[19]: lst[0]['message']['chat']
Out[19]: {'first_name': 'Yuri', 'id': 77777777}

In[20]: lst[0]['message']['chat']['id']
Out[20]: 77777777
```

Comment: как вы на выходе избавились квадратных скобок в Out[17]? или я не правильно понял этот шаг?

Comment: `Out[число]:` не является частей вывода, я это писал в интерпретаторе IPython, который нумерует строки ввода и вывода.

Answer (score 3):

```
from functools import reduce, wraps


def silenced(*exceptions):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return f(*args, **kwargs)
            except exceptions:
                return None
        return wrapper
    return decorator


@silenced(IndexError, KeyError)
def item_getter(container, key):
    if container is not None:
        return container[key]


lst = [{
  'update_id': 138638308, 
  'message': {
    'message_id': 215, 
    'from': {
      'id': 2999, 
      'is_bot': False, 
      'first_name': 'Yuri'}, 
    'chat': {
      'id': 77777777, 
      'first_name': 'Yuri'}
    }
}]
path = [0, 'message', 'chat', 'id']

value = reduce(item_getter, path, lst)
print(value)
```

Comment: Кто как извернётся. :)

Comment: @froxxendsg не удержался от overkill'а :)

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант - анализировать (доставать) в словаре:

```
d = {}
lst = [{'update_id': 138638308, 'message': {'message_id': 215, 'from': {'id': 2999, 'is_bot': False, 'first_name': 'Yuri'}, 'chat': {'id': 77777777, 'first_name': 'Yuri'}}}]
for tsl in lst:
    d.update(tsl) 
d['message']["chat"]['id']
```

Answer (score 1):

Предполагая что `lst` может содержать несколько словарей (вероятно, это приходящие откуда-то данные), можно перебором, например:

```
>>> lst = [
# Первый словарь
{'update_id': 138638308, 'message': {'message_id': 215, 'from': {'id': 2999, 'is_bot': False, 'first_name': 'Yuri'}, 'chat': {'id': 77777777, 'first_name': 'Yuri'}}}, 
# Второй словарь
{'update_id': 138638309, 'message': {'message_id': 215, 'from': {'id': 2999, 'is_bot': False, 'first_name': 'Yuri'}, 'chat': {'id': 786313456456, 'first_name': 'Yuri'}}},
# Третий словарь
{'update_id': 138638310, 'message': {'message_id': 215, 'from': {'id': 2999, 'is_bot': False, 'first_name': 'Yuri'}, 'chat': {'id': 874454646, 'first_name': 'Yuri'}}}
]  # И сколько угодно может быть словарей

>>> for item in lst:
    id = item['message']["chat"]['id'] # В переменную id сохраняем нужное значение и делаем внутри цикла всё что нужно с ней.
    print(id)

# Вывод
77777777
786313456456
874454646
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(lst[0]['message']['chat']['id'])
```